# i want to call a function many time inside my code?

Tags: javascript, keypress

I plan to make this box move every time I click a button 
but the problem is that it works first time when I click `s` or `d` but does not work after that.
So can any one help me to find the solution to my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
 .box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
              </style>
</head>

<body id="bd">

<div class="box"></div>

<script >

document.getElementById('bd').addEventListener('keypress', show);
function show(e){
    let x = e.which;
    if(x == 122){
       // 122 = z
    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.top -='50px' ;      
     }
     else  if(x == 133){
         // 122 = q
     document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.left -='50px' ; 

    }
     else  if(x == 115){
       // 122 = s
     document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.top +='50px' ; 
    }
     else  if(x == 100){
        // // 122 = d
     document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.left +='50px' ;    
    }
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might be looking for something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/z2260xdh/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to perform operation on string. First need to convert in number.

> **Sample:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: black;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="bd">
  <div class="box"></div>

  <script>
    const number = (num) => Number(num.split('px')[0])
    const addBy50 = (num) => `${number(num) + 50}px`
    const subtractBy50 = (num) => `${number(num) - 50}px`
    const style = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style
    document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
      let x = e.which;
      const {
        top,
        left
      } = style
      switch (e.which) {
        case 122:
          style.top = subtractBy50(top);
          break;
        case 113:
          style.left = subtractBy50(left);
          break
        case 115:
          style.top = addBy50(top);
          break
        case 100:
          style.left = addBy50(left);
          break
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and what we call this  const {
        top,
        left
      } = style

Comment: ES6 destructuring assignment   i find what is that thanks

Comment: but const {top, left} = style        style represent an array or an object ?  i try to know the type and i write consolelog(typeof style) and the result is object is this correct

Comment: haha! thanks! it would be great if u can accept as answer! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`element.style.top` and `element.style.left` are strings, so your statements are essentially saying

`element.style.top = "20px" + "50px";`

Instead, consider a separate variable storing position:

```
let positionLeft = 20;

...

if(x == 115){
    positionLeft += 50;
    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.top = positionLeft + 'px'; 
}
```

Comment: but sometimes the movement does not working perfectly